# Is there any solution to generate annotated datas(like JSON) from mask image? (For Mask R-CNN)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm new in deep-learning. While I just tried Mask R-CNN(https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git).
And I successfully ran it from jupyter notebook, and I tried to run with another data such as face data.

But I couldn't find the face data with annotation, only I found was MASK IMAGE(From CelebA dataset).

[Example of Mask Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoLc4.png)

Is there any way to generate annotation(JSON) file from images like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out : https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/250

```
from imantics import Mask, Image, Category

image = Image.from_path('path/to/image.png')
image.add(Mask(array), category=Category("Category Name"))

# JSON of coco
coco_json = image.export(style='coco')
# Saves to file
image.save('coco/annotation.json', style='coco')
```

requirement :

```
pip install imantics
```